# How to invalidate cache for a resource on PUT with nginx

Tags: nginx

As an example, consider

```
location /books/1234 {
    proxy_pass http://backend_server;
    proxy_cache_valid 200 10m;  # override global cache duration for this resource
    proxy_cache_lock on;      # enable cache locking for POST requests
    proxy_cache_lock_timeout 5s;
}
```

In my case `/books/1234` will only change when someone makes an update (PUT request). But I have the cache duration set to 10 minutes, which means that it might take up to 10 minutes before the update is visible. So the question I have is, is there a way to tell NGINX to invalide the cache for this resource when a PUT occurs?

The only way I can think of, is to do something with the `Cache-control` header and add this line to my config

```
proxy_cache_bypass $http_cache_control;
```

and make a `GET` request right after the `PUT` with that headers set to `no-cache`. But allowing this feels like opening a door for hackers (DDOS maybe). So there should be a better way I guess. Any suggestions?